# Hangfire Implementation with MVC Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, orchardcms, hangfire

I have a requirement that implementing the hangfire dashboard inside my application itself.I have a link "Dashboard" in my home page clicking on that Hangfire dashboard should open as the part of my application.

The below code i tried

On click of Dashboard link

```
 public void BuildNavigation(string name, NavigationBuilder builder)
        {
            if (!String.Equals(name, "menu", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return;
            }

            builder
                   .Add(T["Dashboard"], "1", installed => installed.Action("Index", "HangfireDashboard", "Modules.HangfireDashboard"));
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup : StartupBase
{

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=HangfireDashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseHangfireServer(options: new BackgroundJobServerOptions()
        {
            Activator = new JobActivator()
        });
        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/TestPage");


    }

    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(TenenatDbConfigurationProvider.GetDefaultConnectionString()));
        services.AddScoped<INavigationProvider, ModulesMenu>();
    }
}
```

this is opening the index page of the modules not the hangfire dash board.

let me know if anybody have implemented this inside your modules

Thanks

Dev

Comment: Not sure about ASP.NET Core. But in my ASP.NET WebAPI project I can access the dashboard like http://myapp/hangfire without any additional configuration (by default it adds the routes)

Comment: Why is this tagged with 'Orchard'?

Comment: we are  using Orchard framework as well

Answer (score 0):

Don´t know if I got you right - but as fas as I understood you´re trying to access hangfire dashboard with a link.

As Dilhan already commented, the default route is [your site]/hangfire, but as you gave a string-argument to `app.UseHangfireDashboard("/TestPage")` the assigned string is your new route. So if you want to access hangfire-dashboard you need to reference [your site]/TestPage..

Hope that helps :)